# multiple google chart in one page-strange thing are happening

Tags: google-visualization

this is my code:

```
  <html>
  <title>report</title>
  <head>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

     function soso(){
       var data_flow = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data_flow.addColumn('string', 'Version');
       data_flow.addColumn('number','flow');
       data_flow.addRows([['20120125',466.0],['20120130',173.0],['20120203',160.0],['20120208',529.0],['20120213',210.0]]);
       var options = {width: 2200, height: 540,title: ''}; 
       var chart_flow= new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('checkin-column'));
       chart_flow.draw(data_flow, options);
     }
     function loveu()
     {
        var data_flow_1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data_flow_1.addColumn('string', 'Version');
       data_flow_1.addColumn('number','flow');
       data_flow_1.addRows([['20120125',466.0],['20120130',173.0],['20120203',160.0],['20120208',529.0],['20120213',210.0]]);
       var options5 = {width: 2200, height: 540,title: ''};
       var chart_flow_1= new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('redemption-table'));
       chart_flow_1.draw(data_flow_1, options5);
     }
     function drawChart() {
       soso();
       loveu();

     }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <h4>dfs</h4><br>
  <br><br>
  <div id="checkin-column"></div>
    <p></p>
    <div id="redemption-table"></div>
   </body>
   </HTML>
```

When I delete: "< h4 > dfs < / h4 >" I get the charts working fine in iexplorer, but when I don't delete it, the first chart work fine but the second one the axis of it doesn't appear!! Try it and you will see that (on Internet Explorer).
I need a help in solving this issued, I am facing strange behavior of these charts when there is more than one in the same page

Answer (score 1):

Problem: I have 3 charts on a page but the axis for the 3rd chart are not showing in IE

Resolution: I have the 3 divs as separate rows in a table and all 3 charts are now showing their axis!

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: putting the target divs in a table fixed the error for me, too.